# Saber si una tabla existe o no en postgres

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

lo que pasa es que estoy intentando consultar si una tabla *existe* en postgres o no,logré hacer la consulta,el problema es que está consultando si existe en todo el esquema de postgres y no en la base sobre la que estoy ejecutando la consulta y me trae más registros ya que tengo otras bases de datos que tienen tablas con el mismo nombre.Me gustaría que me ayudaran para saber que me hace falta en la consulta. *De antemano gracias.*

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='pais'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta filtrar por `table_schema` para un schema especifico, y `table_catalog` para una db

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='pais' 
 AND table_catalog = 'TUDB'
 AND table_schema = 'TUSCHEMA'
```

Para mas información deberías chequear este link, para la v PSQL V9.2

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/infoschema-tables.html

Saludos.

Comment: Hola disculpa a que te refieres con table_schema es que pensé que era el nombre de la base de datos, pero no funciona, mi versión de postgres es 9.2, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Alli agregue por DB y por schema. Saludos

Comment: Hola gracias, ya encontré la forma no es que estuviera consultando de toda el esquema de postgres o de todas las bases de datos, lo que pasa es que se repetía el resultado dependiendo el número de columnas de la tabla, para mi caso 3, entonces lo que hice fue agregarle el distinct quedando así.        Muchas gracias.                                  SELECT
 DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM
 information_schema. COLUMNS
WHERE
 TABLE_NAME = 'pais'